# How to connect Android with a MySQL database?

Tags: android, mysql

is there an easy way to connect MySQL with an Android application.

I'm using phpMyAdmin to administrate MySQL tasks and i need a way to connect with Android.

Comment: where doed thid mysql server reside

Comment: use Asynktask classes to communicate with mysql database

Answer (score 1):

Check this out :
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm

For me the simplest way is to work with REST (using retrofit library for android).

Answer (score 1):

You should have your PHP scripts which should handle the backend (Server communications) which should return the data required by your android application usually in JSON format. At this stage, you can now use the Volley networking library in Android to handle the JSON data.

You can clone the repo using this: git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley

This is a nice tutorial on getting started with volley: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-introduction-to-volley--cms-23800